# How to resized button in godot

Tags: button, godot

Why when creating a button with a script in the function _ready, these buttons cannot be resized. (And position)

```
var pos
var siz
var yBut = 150
var but

func _ready():
    siz = get_viewport().get_visible_rect().size
    pos = get_viewport().get_visible_rect().position
    but = Button.new()
    $sc/vb.add_child(but, true)
    but.rect_position = pos/2
    but.rect_size = Vector2(siz.x, 150)
```

ps. The buttons are placed in a ScrollContainer in which the vBoxContainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container controls will auto resize and position children controls. Try using the Button's size flags to suggest it's size.

You can also compose ui with multiple levels of other Container controls such as V and HBoxContainer using size flags. This will give you finer control over the whole look of the ui. This will also make it easier to add controls later that will adaptively resize.

You can also set `rect_min_size` and the Container will not resize it any smaller than min size. However, that may break dynamic layout.

Hope this helps!